# Snap Store is not shown in application menu on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: snap, ubuntu-store

I newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 in Lenovo i3 PC, but the Snap Store application is not shown in the application menu.
When I check on Ubuntu store it is shown that the Snap Store is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

The '*Ubuntu Software*' application that you find pre-installed in your system is the Snap Store *itself*. Ubuntu shipped the Snap Store as the default software store application on 20.04 (source: [this OMG! Ubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-snap-store-transition)).

You can verify this by running the command `snap-store` in a Terminal window. It would launch the Ubuntu Software application.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem existed in my pop os. I installed the snap store from scratch, you can try the same by running the commands:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Also instead of snap store you can manage packages with synaptic package manager which I personally prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Snap Store from the terminal instead. Open the terminal and type:

```
snap run snap-store
```

Alternatively you can search for "snap store" in the Software app, click it to bring up the Snap Store information screen, and launch the Snap Store by clicking the    <kbd>Launch</kbd>   button.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a matter of

```
snap remove snap-store
```

and then

```
snap install snap-store
```

and it was added to the menu of programs again